# When may I or may not have unaligned memory access?

Tags: c++, arm

I have a little confusion on when I may have unaligned access and when not.

I know that when I have a void pointer that came from network or somewhere else and there is no guarantee that it aligned with my machine word size, when I cast the pointer and de-referencing it, I need to be carful because I can access unaligned memory.

what I don't know, is when I **don't** need to worry about that, When do I have a guarantee that this will not happen?

considering this function:

```
static int compare_size_t(
  const void * pcv_elem0,
  const void * pcv_elem1) 
{
  size_t sz_elem0;
  size_t sz_elem1;

  sz_elem0 = *static_cast<size_t*>(pcv_elem0);
  sz_elem1 = *static_cast<size_t*>(pcv_elem1);

  if (sz_elem0 > sz_elem1) 
  {
    return 1;
  } 
  else if (sz_elem0 < sz_elem1) 
  {
    return -1;
  } 

  return 0;

}


static void foo(bool * pb_test_passed) 
{
  size_t arr[1024];

  // fill the array with data

  qsort(
    arr,
    1024,
    sizeof(arr[0]),
    compare_size_t);

   // some other code...

}
```

Can I have unaligned access with ARM processor? should I replace

```
sz_elem0 = *static_cast<size_t*>(pcv_elem0);
sz_elem1 = *static_cast<size_t*>(pcv_elem1);
```

with

```
(void) memcpy( 
  &sz_elem0,
  pcv_elem0,
  sizeof(sz_elem0));

(void) memcpy( 
  &sz_elem1,
  pcv_elem1,
  sizeof(sz_elem1));
```

?

Comment: What do you mean a pointer came from a network? Pointers are only valid within the address space of the application. Outside this, pointers are always invalid, no matter if they are aligned or not. Allocating functions return pointers that are suitable for any object.

Comment: *what I don't know, is when I don't need to worry about that*: you should nearly **never** worry about that. All data allocated by C++ will have proper alignment. If you read data from external sources like a file or network, you *shouldn't* cast the data as a struct and read the fields (I think it is what you are talking about). Not only you can have misalignment, but also padding problems and wrong endianness. Instead, use some deserialization library that will read data byte by byte.

Comment: It depends on the origin of the void pointers. If they actually point to existing objects it's safe to cast them back. If they, by contrast, point e.g. at arbitrary bytes in a byte stream of data coming over a network (so that an object doesn't exist there) casting to object type and accessing is UB, and partly exactly because alignment is not guaranteed. Memcpy is the way to go in such cases.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis I mean to pointer to buffer of data that came from external source (like a file or network as prapin mentioned). even if I know its structure, I can't cast directly to struct or object without taking care of alignment and padding issues.

Comment: `sz_elem0 = *static_cast<size_t*>(pcv_elem0);` is already UB unless `pcv_elem0` points to a living `size_t` object, meaning you took the address of a `size_t` and cast it to `void *`. So you don't have to worry about unaligned access, the code is already UB before any of that can happen. Theoretically you have to always `memcpy()` or `bit_cast`. Practically, if you can guarantee alignment and have an aggregate type, it will work.

Comment: the compare function as written can easily fail...almost expected.   But if every time it is used it is used with types the same or larger than what it is cast to then it should work.  but then why use void and create the problem in the first place?

Comment: @old_timer "but then why use void and create the problem in the first place" -for example, because qsort expects to get void pointer, so I must cast to void first and then in compare_size_t cast back to size_t.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to worry about any of this in standard C++ because you can only dereference `T*` if there exists an object of `T` at the address. You can only create `T` by

- `new T(...)` which handles alignment,
- placement new `new (buff) T` where `buff` must be suitably aligned,
- or automatic storage which handles alignment too.
- [Other advanced stuff, not needed to demonstrate the issue]

If `T` is a member, compiler handles alignment during `struct/class` definition.

If there is no such object at the given address and unless `T` is `char`,`unsigned char`, or `std::byte`
(which have alignment 1), you are violating strict aliasing rule by dereferencing `T*` pointer -> UB.

There is a potential issue if you use compiler-specific packing directives. In that case, you must be very careful about passing pointers to unaligned members around. This will generate bus errors if the architecture (ARM) cannot handle unaligned reads/writes or degrade performance(x64) if it can. Accessing the member through its struct like `object.member=5;` is always safe (but maybe slower) since the compiler can see the misalignment and generate appropriate instructions.

So if there are no `size_t` objects  at `pcv_elemX` created by one of the above approaches, you must use memcpy, otherwise you have UB. `memcpy` is safe for this and compiler can often avoid the copy and use the original pointer (while being aware of the possible aliasing).

There is C++20 `std::bit_cast` explicitly designed for this use case.

Comment: There are [many more things](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p0593r6.html) that create things now.

Comment: @ixSci Has that been accepted? But you are right, I forgot about unions at least.

Comment: Yeah, [it was](https://github.com/cplusplus/papers/issues/106).

Comment: `f(void *p) {  Object_T * op = (Object_T *)p; op->member = 5; }` is as unsafe as any other access.

Comment: But I assume you refer to a packed structure `Object_T`; that's an interesting case. Not sure whether and where in the standard that would be covered (because a `member` exists there, so it's fine to cast a void ptr to `object.member` back to `Member_T*`) but if the TU of that function is not aware of its mis-alignment (because it doesn't know that the incoming `void  *` points to a member in a packed struct) it cannot produce the necessary code. Maybe compilers would not mis-align members in packed structs for such platforms.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica I was reffering to `f(int* x); Object o; f(&o.int_member);` If `int_member` is unaligned  due to e.g. `__attribute__((packed))`, then read from `x` in `f` can trigger bus error for ARM. `o.int_member=5;` should be always safe, no matter the packing because compiler can see that and generate appropriate instruction for the given architecture. On the other hand, it will assume that `x` is aligned. I don't think Standard is involved, but yes, there is valid object there, but it exits there only by non-standard means.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica  E.g. [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/WE5sh4ea1), at least sanitizers warn about this. It will work on x64 though just fine. Can't find ARM runner on godbolt right now, I thought there were some.

Comment: You are right, non-standard means, so the standard won't have anything to say.

Comment: The "packed" attribute is basically pointless. Accessing a packed struct more than once will be slower than copying the packed struct into a not packed struct and using that in almost all cases. Using a pointer to a member of a packed struct that isn't itself a packed struct or char type is UB. Basically all the packed struct is good for is calculating offsets for copying (via memcpy or assignment of each member recursively).

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow any reference for access to packed members through "unpacked" pointers being UB? Seems like GCC should somehow specify it if packing is supported.

Comment: @Quimby Indeed. There should be a `[[gnu::packed]] int *p;`. But `&packed.i` just gives `int *` and then access to it causes unaligned errors.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow Okay, did not know that attribute existed, thanks!

Comment: @Quimby The problem is that that attribute can't be applied to fundamental types, only to structs.